# what does this command do for a bert transformers?

Tags: keras, nlp, bert-language-model

```
!pip install transformers 

from transformers import InputExample, InputFeatures
```

What are InputExample and InputFeatures here?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/main_classes/processors#transformers.InputExample).

> Processors
>
> This library includes processors for several traditional tasks. These
> processors can be used to process a dataset into examples that can be
> fed to a model.

And

> class transformers.InputExample
>
> A single training/test example for simple sequence classification.

As well as

> class transformers.InputFeatures
>
> A single set of features of data. Property names are the same names as
> the corresponding inputs to a model.

So basically InputExample is just a raw input and InputFeatures is the (numerical) feature representation of that Input that the model uses.

I couldn't find any tutorial explicitly explaining this but you can check out Chapter 4 (From text to features) in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-chaturangarajapakshe-text-classification-with-transformer-models-d370944b50ca) where it is nicely explained on an example.

From my experience the transformers library has an absolute ton of classes and structures so going too deep into the technical implementation can make it easy to get lost in. For starters I would recommend trying to get an idea of the broader picture by just getting some example projects to work as well as checking out their  [Course](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/1?fw=tf).